# How to create functions to be reused in C#

Tags: c#

I am working on the MACD.  The MACD function is getting too long and I am repeating code.  I want to create a function SMA and call it to the MACD function. I created this class but I get an error :

```
namespace myBackEnd
{
   public class SMA
{
    public decimal SMA (Queue<Models.DateClose> queue, int period) <--- error here
    {
        decimal average, sum=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < period; i++)
        {
            Models.DateClose dateClose;
            dateClose = queue.Dequeue();
            sum += dateClose.Close;
        }
        return average = sum/period;
    }
}
```

I get an error 'member name cannot be the same as enclosing name".  How can I fix this?

Comment: You can't have a method (/function) with the same name as the class it belongs to. That naming, a "function" with the same name as the class is reserved for constructors (which your SMA.SMA is not. How can you fix it... Change the name

Comment: Fly, then how do I call the method?  can I have the method all by itself and not in a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's cause you can't have a method name defined same as the class name (Exception: `Constructor`). Compiler may think it's a constructor but it can't be since the member function has return type and constructor can't. So essentially provide a separate meaningful name like

```
public decimal SMAMethod (Queue<Models.DateClose> queue, int period)
```

Answer (score -1):

In C# you are not allowed to have methods named the same as the type you are putting them inside. So since your class is named SMA, you aren't allowed to name any method inside there SMA. Try another name

```
public decimal DoStuff (Queue<Models.DateClose> queue, int period)
```

(Obviously not DoStuff, since that isn't really self-documenting, but something relevant to your use case)